# How to make background images stretch and change every 3 seconds in asp.net

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I am trying to make a slide show for the background image. this is the code so far:

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function startTimer() {
              setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
          }

          var images = [], x = -1;
          images[0] = "assets/Images/Image1.jpg";
          images[1] = "assets/Images/Image2.jpg";
          images[2] = "assets/Images/Image3.jpg";
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="CenterContents"  onload = "changeImage()">
        <%-- write everything here --%>


        <img id="img" src="assets/Images/Image3.jpg">
        <button type="button" onclick="displayPreviousImage()">Previous</button>
       <button type="button" onclick="displayNextImage()">Next</button>

        <%-- dont write anything lower than this --%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I was trying to change the code image with this function:
`setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);`

But is not working. Any suggestions?

Also, how can I set the image to stretch?
I used `background-size: cover`
But is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stretch image add `width: 100%;` and to automate image change add

In javascript

```
 <script> document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { startTimer(); }); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function at the onload of the body tag in html as shown below,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
              document.getElementById("img").alt = "image"+x;
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
              document.getElementById("img").alt = "image"+x;
          }

          function startTimer() {
              setInterval(displayNextImage, 5000);
          }

          var images = [], x = -1;
          images[0] = "assets/Images/Image1.jpg";
          images[1] = "assets/Images/Image2.jpg";
          images[2] = "assets/Images/Image3.jpg";
    </script>

</head>
<body onload = "startTimer()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="CenterContents"  >
        <!-- write everything here -->


        <img id="img" src="assets/Images/Image3.jpg" alt="image0">
        <button type="button" onclick="displayPreviousImage()">Previous</button>
       <button type="button" onclick="displayNextImage()">Next</button>

        <!-- dont write anything lower than this -->
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```